# C# .net Core web Api Get request # parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, vk

I use authorization via `oauth.vk.com` [Docs here](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites)

When I call on web-browser

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1&display=page&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&scope=friends&response_type=token&v=5.80
```

After I sign in to `vk.com` and accept permissions to my server `vk.com` send `Get` request like this:

```
http://example.com/callback#access_token=c9186f0de67865740b9bd920a67320142434422007d16cf79031734fd450657cd4ba221106ce7232e74b7&expires_in=86400&user_id=1&email=example@mail.com
```

I don't know how to take #access_token in my Get method

Parameters with ? like expires_in, user_id and email I can take like this

```
[Route("vkauth")]
public class VKAuthController : Controller {
  [HttpGet]
  public string Get_VkAuth([FromQuery] string access_token, string expires_in, string user_id, string email) {
}
```

But how to take parameter #access_token?

Comment: Please don’t consider implementing OAuth manually but just use ASP.NET Core’s authentication stack for it. There is even a [VKontakte](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Vkontakte) plugin to enable authentication without much effort.

Comment: Nothing after the `#` reaches the server. You are attempting to use a a client-side implementation in server-side code. That's the first signal you are not doing it correctly

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but how to be in client side - with this token I need to make another HTTP-request - how it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct Answer in comment by [camilo-terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141621/camilo-terevinto)

> Nothing after the # reaches the server. You are attempting to use a a
>   client-side implementation in server-side code. That's the first
>   signal you are not doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Just use the HttpRequestMessage in the function and extract the token via the header (if the token is send using headers: Authorization)

For eg:

```
public string Get_VkAuth(HttpRequestMessage request,[FromQuery] string access_token, string expires_in, string user_id, string email) {

 String access_token= request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();

}
```

Comment: I've got Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You cannot inject `HttpRequestMessage` in ASP.NET Core. But you can just access the controller’s `Request` property to retrieve header values.

Comment: @poke I've trying like `Request.Headers["Authorization"]` and like this  `Request.Headers["access_token"]`  but there is no header

Comment: @IgorCova Yeah, as Avy mentioned in the answer, you can only retrieve the token if it is sent as part of the Authorization header.

Comment: @put I can't rule this - vk send me Get request like this http://example.com/callback#access_token=token